# create directed arrow plots of two variables using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two variables `(V1,V2)` measured on same subject (`id`) at two time points (`timepoint`). I want to have a scatterplot with arrow paths to show how values moved from `T1` to `T2` for the same subject.

In my example, some subjects do not have change in `V1` nor `V2`, it would be ideal to show just as one dot for those sub (sub 1 for example), but I am OK with two dots for two visits, since they will be overlap. There are also sub with a decrease in either `V1` or `V2` (sub 2 for example), those sub were shown in red arrow above. The third group of subjects show an increase in either `V1` or `V2` **(sub 6 and 7): these sub were in green**.

**However, what I really need is all arrows point from `T1` to `T2`. That is I hope the green arrow change direction.**

The dataset can be generated by:

```
datatest <- data.frame(timepoint =rep(seq(2,1),8), 
                   id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8),
                   V1= c( 30.29, 30.29, 21.60, 31.43, 20.75,20.75, 21.60, 30.03, 21.60, 31.30, 31.60, 21.72, 31.6, 20.02, 11.60, 20.16),
                   V2=c(40, 40, 30.78, 41.63, 40.41, 40.41,30.78, 40.97, 20.78, 40.84, 41.85, 41.85, 40.78, 31.79,20.78, 30.23))
```

which looks like this:

```
   timepoint id    V1    V2
1          2  1 30.29 40.00
2          1  1 30.29 40.00
3          2  2 21.60 30.78
4          1  2 31.43 41.63
5          2  3 20.75 40.41
6          1  3 20.75 40.41
7          2  4 21.60 30.78
8          1  4 30.03 40.97
9          2  5 21.60 20.78
10         1  5 31.30 40.84
11         2  6 31.60 41.85
12         1  6 21.72 41.85
13         2  7 31.60 40.78
14         1  7 20.02 31.79
15         2  8 11.60 20.78
16         1  8 20.16 30.23
```

To generate the (wrong) plot I currently have, please run the codes below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lemon)
ggplot(datatest, aes(V1,V2,color=as.factor(timepoint),group=id)) +ggtitle("V2 vs V1 from T1 to T2")+
  geom_pointline(linesize=1, size=2, distance=4, arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(0.1, "inches"), ends = "first", type = "open") )+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,33), breaks=seq(0,30,10), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,43), breaks=seq(0,44,10),expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","red"))+labs(color  = "Timepoint")
```

The plot currently looks like this:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this get you closer?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


data <- data.frame(timepoint =rep(seq(2,1),8), 
                       id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8),
                       V1= c( 30.29, 30.29, 21.60, 31.43, 20.75,20.75, 21.60, 30.03, 21.60, 31.30, 31.60, 21.72, 31.6, 20.02, 11.60, 20.16),
                       V2=c(40, 40, 30.78, 41.63, 40.41, 40.41,30.78, 40.97, 20.78, 40.84, 41.85, 41.85, 40.78, 31.79,20.78, 30.23))


data <- data %>%
  mutate(row_id = paste0("T", timepoint)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
              names_from = row_id,
              values_from = c(V1, V2)) %>%
  mutate(colour = ifelse((V1_T1 > V1_T2) | (V2_T1 > V2_T2), "red", "green"))

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = V1_T1, y = V2_T1)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = V1_T2, y = V2_T2)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = V1_T1, xend = V1_T2, y = V2_T1 , yend = V2_T2, colour = colour),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3,"cm"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 33),
    breaks = seq(0, 30, 10),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 43),
    breaks = seq(0, 44, 10),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  )
```

You can filter the object `data` to remove those lines where V1 and V2 do not change and not draw the lines with length zero.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!