# Visualize the change of observations in a scatterplot by arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have scatterplot with observations (x, y) of 5 countries (A, B, C, D, E) at two different points in time (2016, 2020).

I want to plot a scatterplot, coloring the observations (grouped by year) and indicating the direction of change by an arrow (grouped by country).

Here is my code:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggrepel)

country <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

year <- c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)

x <- c(1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 3, 6, 8, 15, 12)

y <- c(3, 2, 6, 8, 10, 5, 4, 4, 13, 17)

df <- data_frame(country, year, x, y)

df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group = country)) +
    geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, stroke = 2,
              color = year, fill = "white") +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
    geom_path(arrow = arrow(angle = 30, length = unit(2, "mm"),
                        type="closed")) +
    geom_label_repel(aes(label = ifelse(year == "2020", country,"")),
                     nudge_x = 1, direction = "y", hjust = "right")
```

I come across two problems:

1. Why am I not able to color the observations in my preferred colors?
   `scale_color_manual(values=c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))`
2. How can I customize the arrows, so that there is small distance from the starting-point and a small distance from the end-point? (the arrows should not touch the observations)

Comment: For color, perhaps you wanted `aes(color = factor(year))` in `geom_point` for your 2 years?

Comment: Try `lemon::geom_pointline`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62336117/6574038

Comment: Although `geom_path` seems logical here, if you want an arrow on each segment, I think you need `geom_segment` instead.

Comment: @ Ben: thank you, but the `factor(year)` has to be in the first line: `ggplot(aes(x, y, group = country, color = factor(year))) +`

Comment: @ jay.sf: `lemon::geom_pointline`does not work. Some of the arrows show in the wrong direction (not from 2016 to 2020, but the other way around). Isn't there another way to tell `geom_path`or segment to start the arrow with some space to the point and end it again with some space to the final point?